# PHP Errors with Drupal 8 (Shared Hosting)

Tags: 8, installation, composer

Using Bitbucket, I've cloned my Drupal 8 site to my Media Temple server. It is shared hosting. Anyways, I'm getting the following php warning and error:

```
Warning: require(/nfs/c11/h04/mnt/55555/domains/domain.com/html/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c11/h04/mnt/55555/domains/domain.com/html/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/nfs/c11/h04/mnt/55555/domains/domain.com/html/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-7.0.6/share/pear') in /nfs/c11/h04/mnt/55555/domains/domain.com/html/autoload.php on line 17
```

This is my first time working with Drupal 8. I've done some research and troubleshooting, but I've not been able to solve the issue.

I'm actually having a similar issue with a separate D8 website on Bluehost (CPanel). Has anything run into this before? If so, what steps were taken to resolve the issue?

Comment: Unless your host does some magic on your behalf, you'll need to commit all the vendor/ files to the repo and push those too. By default the whole vendor folder is ignored through .gitignore, because any new server that runs the code should execute composer install first. Evidently your host haven't done that so you need to

Comment: @Clive While your suggestion did not solve my particular issue, it did help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Clive's advice, I committed the /vendor and /core directories. The php errors shown in my initial question were resolved, but new, similar php errors appeared. After much trial and error, I discovered the Drupal VM was added some sort of configuration to the Drupal install. Whatever that configuration may be, it did not translate to the server environment. I downloaded a fresh Drupal 8 copy and manually installed it. After I pushed up the fresh files, it worked like a charm.